# How to do FFT on I and Q DATA in Python

Tags: dft, power-spectral-density

I am Working on a Satellite data, where information is stored in a Raw data exchange format .prd file, i have extracted the information in csv file where i got the I and Q data in decimal, now i wanted to apply fourier transform, power spectral density for getting the doppler. i am working on python can anyone help me regarding this...

Note that i have a large data set which is about 144crores but i have divided it into chunks..

Thank you

Comment: Hi! Just a remark: outside of India, nearly nobody knows what crores are, and also, crores is just a multiplier, not a unit of storage. Your data size mostly comes from the conversion into a very wasteful and unsuitable intermediate format, the text-based CSV format. After loading, you'll need less memory than your CSV files. That's good news!

Comment: Sadly, we can't tell you what FFTs to do, because you haven't told us what you need. You'll need to sit down and figure out which number of points you need to get the Doppler resolution you want. Don't say "as much as possible", that won't work, but state actual numbers!

Comment: One obvious answer to your question would be “use an FFT routine on your data of interest”. Of course, as Marcus Müller also suggested in the other comments, this would not be a good answer (doesn’t seem to help in any way) but this is mostly due to a lack of clarity in the question. I suggest you rewrite your question from the viewpoint of a third-person with enough knowledge to answer but completely ignorant to your specific problem.

Comment: I just wanted to know how to proceed further with in_phase and Quadrature_phase data which is of some value like -4, 10, 20, -30 so on.. if i want to do fft on this so what to do like should we first change it to complex signal?

Comment: we can't tell you. We know nothing about your data nor what you need to do with it. How can we tell you what to do? Your question is like asking "I have a bag of flour. What do I do with it?" without even telling us what you want to cook or bake.